# Best practice store secrets in Javascript Express App

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager

I have created a simple NodeJS REST API using express and AWS lambda. I started off using environmental variables and now I have process.env all over my API.

However, Im just starting out testing the secretmanager in AWS. It seems to be working fine. I built a module getAWSsecrets.js which I can easily access by simple running:

```
async function testFunc() {
  let credentials = await getSecrets();
  console.log(credentials);
}
```

This is working as intended and the getSecrets() method returns a json object with all the secrets I need. But at each location in my app I need to make this API request to get the secrets. Is there possibly a better way to somehow cache the secrets to avoid having to call the secretmanager over and over.

Having said this, perhaps it is the most secure? How do I proceed, what is considered best practice? Perhaps this is no issue, it is simply my gut feeling saying that this seems "clunky".

Comment: the normal best practice is to use `process.env`, on an express app you can either use a library called dotenv for loading environments in node from a text file on the app root, or somewhere else on the server. For lambda you would add the env variable to the aws secrets manager for the lambda interface and load through `process.env`. At the start of your file you can also load `const { MYVAR } = process.env` if you want to shorten

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On every cold start (first run) fetch all secrets and use them.

```js
let credentials;
let coldstart = false;

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
   if(!coldstart){
     credentials = await getSecrets();
     coldstart=true;
   }
}
```

Comment: When you say "use them" are you referring to previous answer from @alilland. Are you suggesting to export environmental variables from (process.env) within that coldstart if-statement?

Because my credentials are needed in many different modules. Or are you suggesting that I pass around the credentials variable to where it is needed?

Comment: As I don't know your code structure, you could pass it in multiple ways.
I would create a separate module dealing with secrets and use it. You could load once the secrets and get the secrete service whenever you want.
```const mySecretService = SecretService.get(); mySecretService.get("secretKey");```

Comment: I thought I understod but I keep encountering issues with how to implement this solution. For example: I have an "authController in which I have this function`const signToken = (id) => {
  return jwt.sign({ id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN,
  });
};`

How do I get the secrets into that function? Every promise can only be called within .then(). I just don't know how to get the keys out from the "promise". I feel as If I need to wrap my entire application into a promise. Could you supply with further guidance?